Initial setup of MusiXTex on VSC
MacBookPro 2019 Running Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68) 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

tlmgr info musixtex
installed:   Yes
revision:    70804
sizes:       src: 49k, doc: 4489k, run: 653k, bin: 9k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.38


tlmgr info pmx
installed:   Yes
revision:    65926
sizes:       doc: 1265k, run: 33k, bin: 1465k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 3.00

I have updated everything I can think of!
This is the full text of the sample pmx file file I'm using as an MWE.
\clef treble
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
\notes
c'8 d'8 e'8 f'8 g'8 a'8 b'4 |
\endnotes

I have "render whitespace: all" on so I can see that there are no invisible tricky characters.
The file is UTF8, LF, and Plain Text as reported by the bottom of the VSC window. I ran cat -v and verified that there are no extraneous characters.
From the terminal within VSC, I run this, with the following output:
name-of-macbook: prompt$ pmxab twinkle.pmx
 This is PMX, Version 3.00 , 7 Feb 23 
 Opening twinkle.pmx                                    

 Starting first PMX pass
fmt: read unexpected character
apparent state: internal I/O
last format: (f1.0)0F
lately reading sequential formatted internal IO
Abort trap: 6
name-of-macbook: prompt$ 

I am at my wits end! And increasingly certain that it's something obvious. I have tried to give all the information I can, but don't hesitate to ask if I've left out something salient.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have used!

My question is how to make a pmx file compile with pmxab. Which then turns it into TeX code. So, in this instance, I'm not working with TeX code. However, placing something like this:
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{1}
\nobarnumbers
\generalmeter{\empty}
\generalsignature{-1}
\startextract
\NOtes
\qu f \qu h | \hu h
% \hu h \ca h \ca g |
% \qu f \qu h \qu j |
\enotes
\endextract
\end{music}
Into a TeX file compiles just fine. It just doesn't allow for more complicated scores. Does that answer the question?
